# how to create database using wampserver and to connect with the php page

Tags: php, html, mysql, wampserver

I have created the webpage frontend design for a login page and saved it as `.php` file.

I have even installed wampserver.

Give me some idea how to connect a mysql database wampserver and my login page.

Is it possible to use the database option given in wampserver inside the tools?

If it is possible, how we can connect to the login page? Please give some idea...

Comment: Have you tried anything? Searching for PHP and Mysql tutorials? This site will generally help with specific problems rather than can someone write some code for me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you connect to your local phpmyadmin? Have you created a database yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create the database in wampserver in  Phpmyadmin and can create the tables also.

The following is the code to connect to database

```
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("database1",$dbhandle) // "database1" is the database name
 or die("Could not select database1");

//execute the SQL query and return records .. insert ur login info also
$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid  FROM login"); // "login" is table
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
$result1 = INSERT INTO login (id, name, password) VALUES
('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['password']."'); // The values which
                                                        //you entered in the login form

} else {
 echo "This login name already exists";
}
?>
This is the simple way to connect the database and insert the data into tables. But 
dont forget to create database and tables in phpmyadmin before inserting the data
```